Tailwind not applying gradients
I cannot get a simple gradient to work at all in one Tailwind website yet can in the same setup with another Tailwind website.
This is the HTMl in both projects:
<div class="w-full h-[400px] bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-500">Hey</div>

In the project where it works fine, the browser css inspecter shows this:

However in the project where it isn't working it looks like this:

For some reason there is a --tw-gradient-to style and I do not know where it is getting that from and the position isn't set.
I have read in other posts on this problem that you should ensure any color / backgroundImage class reference in tailwind.config should be inside
theme:{
   extend:{
      ...
   }
}

otherwise my classes can be overridden but I have all that set as recommended. So what else can I do to try and track down the problem. I'm using tailwind 3.4.3. Thanks

Just a quick question, are there any differences in the tailwind version you're using in the projects? That, differences in your tailwind config or any other libraries that change the tailwind behaviour are the only things that come to mind.

You're absolutely right. In the project where it works Tailwind is 3.0.23. When I upgraded it to 3.4.3 the same problem happened and when I downgraded it back again, everything was fine again. Unfortunately downgrading the other project where it hasn't been working at all seems to have opened a can of worms. Guess I need to rebuild my gulp file. But thanks for your help.

Alright, great that you've managed to find the problem. I wish you good luck with the project!
